# ReactJS - Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled - edit function

Tags: reactjs

Hi I'm newbie of react and now I'm starting to learn the basic full-stack concept.

I want to make when User clicked the 'edit' button, the data's in the input text still remained in the text box before user click edit.

but I faced this error

Warning: A component is changing a controlled input of type text to be uncontrolled. Input elements should not switch from controlled to uncontrolled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

how can I solve this problem?

thank you in advance!

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class Edit extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super (props);
        this.onChangeName = this.onChangeName.bind(this);
        this.onChangePosition = this.onChangePosition.bind(this);
        this.onChangePhone = this.onChangePhone.bind(this);
        this.onChangePasscode = this.onChangePasscode.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            name:"",
            position: "",
            phone:"",
            passcode: ""
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:8888/reactJsCRUD/getById.php?id='+this.props.match.params.id)
         .then(response => {
            this.setState({
                name:response.data.employeeName,
                postition:response.data.employeePosition,
                phone: response.data.employeePhone,
                passcode:response.data.passcode
            });
         })
         .catch(function(error) {
             console.log(error);
         })
    }

    onChangeName(e) {
        this.setState({
            name: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangePosition(e) {
        this.setState({
            position: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangePhone(e) {
        this.setState({
            phone:e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangePasscode(e) {
        this.setState({
            passcode: e.target.value
        });
    }
    onSubmit(e) {
        
    } 



    render() {
        return (
          <div style={{ marginTop: 10 }} className="w-50 p-3">
            <h3> Add New Employee</h3>
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
              <div className="form-group-3">
                <label>Name: </label>
                <input type="text" className="form-control"  value={this.state.name} onChange={this.onChangeName} />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor= "positionFormSelect">Position: </label>
                <select className="form-control" id="positionFormSelect" value={this.state.position} onChange={this.onChangePosition}>
                  <option>Select the position</option>
                  <option value= "manager">Manager</option>
                  <option value= "server">Server</option>
                  <option value= "cook">Cook</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label>Phone: </label>
                <input type="text" className="form-control" value={this.state.phone} onChange = {this.onChangePhone}/>
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label>Passcode: </label>
                <input type="text" className="form-control" value= {this.state.passcode}onChange = {this.onChangePasscode}/>
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <input
                  type="submit"
                  value="Edit Employee"
                  className="btn btn-primary"
                />
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        );
      }
}
 
export default Edit;
```

Comment: Hey Guys it got a solution. the problem was that in the PHP file :) thank you all !

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a typo here:

```
 <input type="text" className="form-control" value={this.state.posscode} onChange={this.onChangePasscode}/>
```

value should be `this.state.passcode`

Comment: um... even change the my typo, still got the same error

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are setting the state in **componentDidMount** and that is why it is showing you a **warning**.

**Because** you are using that state for **controlled** component and if that state get updated from outside of **event handler** then it will always shows warning as a alert that your state that seems to be used for **controlled** component, now getting updated outside the scope of controlled component. So **advice** is that if you want to use state for **controlled** component, then make sure that specific state do not gets updated from anywhere else.

That's why it is giving you a warning of **uncontrolled** component because your state is not controlled now as it is getting updated outside of **controlled** component scope.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I got the solution.
The problem was in the PHP file!

```
<?php
require_once "cors.php";
require_once "connect.php";

cors();
$con = connect();

$id = $_GET['id'];

// Get by id
$sql = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE employeeId = {$id} LIMIT 1";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
print_r($row) 
echo $json = json_encode($row);

exit;
```

because of print_r($row), the got data also had array and that's why I could not access response.data properly in React :) thank you all !